# Install boot usb key doesn't see my drive (laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I created a bootable usb key in order to install Ubuntu on my new laptop as a dual boot because windows is already here.

So I went to "Managing drives" in windows and created some space (it should be good since its draw with diagonal grey straps ^^).
I also removed Secure boot just in case.
But whatever I try, when I want to install, the setup process doesn't see my drive. It just sees the usb key it's launched on. 
And it's not like "I see the drive but not the free space" ... no : there is nothing here.

What's the matter ?

Infos (just in case) : Windows 10 Pro
Dell PHP105 Model XPS 159550

SC : [what i See, when I click the + or "change..." it either freeze or launch the try boot version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOW9k.jpg)

UPDATE : Disable fast startup in windows didn't help.

Comment: Can you please provide a picture from the "something else" option in the installer?